# Exception while sending objects from one activity to another for the second time

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing a simple mobile application where a user logs in and logs out. While the user is logged in, he can access multiple pages (activity). 
The following is my mainactivity.java:

```
package org.hos.view;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hos.application.LocalDatabaseConnection;
import org.hos.application.LoggedInUser;
import org.hos.controller.LogInController;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener, Serializable
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    LogInController lc=new LogInController();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        View layout=findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login); 
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        EditText id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String name = lc.login(id.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), this);
        //String name = conn.getUsername(id.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        if(name!=null)
        {
            LoggedInUser user=new LoggedInUser();
            user.setUserId(name);
            user.setPrivilege(1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,LoggedInActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LoggedInUser",user);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

As you can see the onclick method, an intent with a loggedinuser object is passed to the second activity. This objuect is received in the next activity. Here's my loggedinactivity.java:

```
package org.hos.view;

import org.hos.application.LoggedInUser;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LoggedInActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button logout;
    LoggedInUser user;
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);
        user = (LoggedInUser) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("LoggedInUser");
        setTitle("Hello "+user.getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logged_in, menu);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.view_graph)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ViewGraphActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LoggedInUser", user);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.equals(logout))
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LoggedInUSer", user);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
        }
    }
}
```

So this activity again has a third activity connected which again is sent the logged in user object. It is received the same way. Heres my view graph.java:

```
package org.hos.view;

import org.hos.application.LoggedInUser;

import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class ViewGraphActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    LoggedInUser user;
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_graph);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        user = (LoggedInUser) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("LoggedInUser");
        setTitle("Hello "+user.getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_graph, menu);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,LoggedInActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LoggedInUser", user);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My problem is for the first time when a user logins, the loggedinactivity.java saves the object and passes to the viewgraphactivity.java class. But while returning back from viewgraphactivity to loggedinactivity, i get the following exception:

> 11-07 13:53:39.258: E/AndroidRuntime(6165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-07 13:53:39.258: E/AndroidRuntime(6165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start >activity ComponentInfo{org.hos.view/org.hos.view.LoggedInActivity}: >java.lang.NullPointerException

Why can't loggedinactivity again take the object sent by viewgraphactivity?

Can anyone tell me why do I get this problem? And if there are any solutions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the problem because the object "user" is not declared when it is called by viewgraphactivty as when an activity is called, only the oncreate method is called and hence the object is never declared as LoggeInUser and assigned a value to it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The only way to pass Custom object though intent is making it Serializable. Check the below link for more deatils

Person mPerson = new Person();  
mPerson.setName("Leon");  
mPerson.setAge(25);

Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,ObjectTranDemo1.class);   
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();  
mBundle.putSerializable(SER_KEY,mPerson);  
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);   

More details : http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing.html
```

Comment: Yes i did this, the object LoggedInUser is serialiazable. As i have mentioned in my question, I am able to send the intent object from the main page to second and then to the third but not backwards. When I click the "back" button, which i have enabled using getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); from the third page to the second I get this exception.

Comment: Thanks spurthi, Parceable made my work easy rather than serialization